# Retrieving value of an Id from one service based on Id from another service

Tags: angular

I am writing an angular application that retrieves jobs which includes customer name. While storing the data in the jobs table , I am storing customerId. Hence the JobModel contains CustomerId.

In my angular job component, I am injecting the customer and job service. I need to retrieve the customer name from customer service based on the CustomerId returned by the Jobservice.

How do I achieve that

Component

```
constructor(
    private customerService: CustomerService,
    private jobService: JobService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerService.GetCustomers().subscribe(customers => this.customers = customers);
    this.jobService.GetJobs().subscribe(jobs => this.jobs = jobs);
  }
```

Html

```
<h2>Jobs list</h2>
<table spacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>When</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let job of jobs">
      <td>{{job.customer}}</td>
      <td>{{job.when | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/job', job.jobId]">Open</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Model

```
export interface JobModel {
  jobId: number;
   customerId: number;
  when: Date;
}
```

Customer

```
export interface CustomerModel {
  customerId: number;
  name: string;
  type: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the name of the customer on the job. I would try something like this:

```
this.jobs.forEach((job) => {
  job.customerName = this.customers.find((customer) => customer.customerId === job.customerId).name;
});
```

Edit: with zip from rxjs:

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs';
...
zip(this.customerService.GetCustomers(), this.jobService.GetJobs()).subscribe([customers, jobs] => {
    this.customers = customers;
    this.jobs = jobs;
    this.jobs.forEach((job) => {
      job.customerName = this.customers.find((customer) => customer.customerId === job.customerId).name;
    });
});
```

Comment: There should be two properties on the JobModel right. Ideally customerId: number; and customerName: string

Comment: I am however passing only customerId to the server

Comment: I updated my answer. This should set the customerName on the job based on the customerId attached to the job and the array of customers. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: So yes there should be customerId and customerName on the model, but if you only store the id in the database you can always get the name from the customers table.

Comment: Do I need to write the above logic after this.jobService.GetJobs().subscribe(jobs => this.jobs = jobs);

Comment: Yes, although because of concurrency it's possible for this to still run first. I would zip the two calls together and put the code inside of the subscribe function.

Comment: How do i do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219379/discussion-between-tom-and-jacob-p).